# ARCore tracking which point on a smartphone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

The ARCore tracking origin (0,0,0) is the real world position where the AR session starts with, but who knows which point on a smartphone does ARCore tracking?

Answer (score 0):

The tracking space pose is mapped to the Camera's relative transform in Unity world space.

So what you want is to convert from World Coordinates (Pose in ARCore) to 2D Screen Coordinates.

This can be calculated manually (finding Transformation Matrix etc) or using the in-build method like this: `arSceneView.getScene().getCamera().worldToScreenPoint();`